# Is this homebrew "Sir Knight" class balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, class

I'm here today to ask whom it may concern to read through this class' description. I would ask your answers to address this class in terms of balancing, its features fitting with image of a medieval knight(of course in a fantasy setting) and on your overall feeling. I am also posting two subclasses, to flesh out the possible character for PCs more. What I would like to hear mostly  about are those three things:

- Is this class outperforming another available classes, or is it underperforming?  What are its weakest and strengths?
- Can this class offer versatility in creating PCs, or is it a bottleneck for creating a goody two-shoes?
- What would anchor valid additional subclass' options, or improve those present already?

The idea behind the class was to make a specialist whose training and education made his/hers horizons broader, and skiss more refined. Abilities were meant to cover a fair bit of possibilities, but enforce thinking what features would be best to use, not spamming everything you have in two turns in combat.

If someone wants to read an introduction to the class like in official sources, it can be found [here](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Sir_Knight_(5e_Class)) at dandwiki.

And while comments are insightful, I would prefer answers.

> **Class Features**
> As a Sir Knight you gain the following class features.
>
> **Hit Points Hit Dice**: 1d10 per Sir Knight level Hit Points at 1st
> Level: 10 + Constitution modifier
>
> **Hit Points at Higher Levels**: 1d10
> (or 6) + Constitution modifier per Sir Knight level after 1st
>
> **Proficiencies Armor**: All armors, shields
>
> **Weapons**: Simple weapons,
> martial weapons Tools: Calligrapher's supplies, vehicles (land)
>
> **Saving Throws**: Strength, Dexterity
>
> **Skills**: choose three from Athletics, Stealth, History, Religion, Animal handling, Persuasion, Intimidation
>
> **Equipment** You start with the following equipment, in addition to the
> equipment granted by your background:
>
> - (a) chain mail or (b) scale mail or (c) leather armor (a)
> - a martial weapon and a shield or (b) two martial weapons
> - (a) ranged martial weapon and 20 arrows or (b) ranged martial weapon and 20 bolts (a)
> - Diplomat's Pack or (b) Explorer's Pack or (c) Scholar's Pack
>
> #### Table: The Sir Knight
>
> | Level | Proficiency Bonus | Features |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1st | +2 | Fighting style |
> | 2nd | +2 | Weapon Mastery, As Good as My Word |
> | 3rd | +2 | Way of Life |
> | 4th | +2 | Ability Score Improvement |
> | 5th | +3 | Extra attack |
> | 6th | +3 | Way of Life feature |
> | 7th | +3 | Weapon Mastery improvement |
> | 8th | +3 | Ability Score Improvement |
> | 9th | +4 | Way of Life feature |
> | 10th | +4 | Ability Score Improvement |
> | 11th | +4 | Extra attack(2) |
> | 12th | +4 | Ability Score Improvement |
> | 13th | +5 | Way of Life feature |
> | 14th | +5 | Weight control,Weapon Mastery improvement |
> | 15th | +5 | Paragon of Verity |
> | 16th | +5 | Ability Score Improvement |
> | 17th | +6 | Golden soul |
> | 18th | +6 | Perfect warrior |
> | 19th | +6 | Ability Score Improvement |
> | 20th | +6 | Way of Life feature |
>
> #### Fighting style
>
> You adopt a particular style of fighting as your specialty. Choose one of the following options. You can't take the
> same Fighting Style option more than once, even if you get to choose
> again.
>
> **Archery** You gain a +2 bonus to attack rolls you make with ranged weapons.
>
> **Blind Fighting** You have blindsight with a range of 10 feet. Within that range, you can effectively see anything that isn't behind total
> cover, even if you're blinded or in darkness. Moreover, you can see an
> invisible creature within that range, unless the creature successfully
> hides from you.
>
> **Defense** While you are wearing armor, you gain a +1 bonus to AC.
>
> **Dueling** When you are wielding a melee weapon in one hand and no other weapons, you gain a +2 bonus to damage rolls with that weapon.
>
> **Great Weapon Fighting** When you roll a 1 or 2 on a damage die for an attack you make with a melee weapon that you are wielding with two
> hands, you can reroll the die and must use the new roll, even if the
> new roll is a 1 or a 2. The weapon must have the two-handed or
> versatile property for you to gain this benefit.
>
> **Interception** When a creature you can see hits a target, other than you, within 5 feet of you with an attack, you can use your reaction to
> reduce the damage the target takes by 1d10 + your proficiency bonus
> (to a minimum of 0 damage). You must be wielding a shield or a simple
> or martial weapon to use this reaction.
>
> **Protection** When a creature you can see attacks a target other than you that is within 5 feet of you, you can use your reaction to impose
> disadvantage on the attack roll. You must be wielding a shield.
>
> **Superior Technique** You learn one maneuver of your choice from among those available to the Battle Master archetype. If a maneuver
> you use requires your target to make a saving throw to resist the
> maneuver's effects, the saving throw DC equals 8 + your proficiency
> bonus + your Strength or Dexterity modifier (your choice).
>
> You gain one superiority die, which is a d6 (this die is added to any
> superiority dice you have from another source). This die is used to
> fuel your maneuvers. A superiority die is expended when you use it.
> You regain your expended superiority dice when you finish a short or
> long rest.
>
> **Thrown Weapon Fighting** You can draw a weapon that has the thrown property as part of the attack you make with the weapon. In addition, when you hit with a ranged attack using a thrown weapon, you gain a +2 bonus to the damage roll.
>
> **Two-Weapon Fighting** When you engage in two-weapon fighting, you can add your ability modifier to the damage of the second attack.
>
> **Unarmed Fighting** Your unarmed strikes can deal bludgeoning damage equal to 1d6 + your Strength modifier on a hit. If you aren't wielding
> any weapons or a shield when you make the attack roll, the d6 becomes
> a d8.
> At the start of each of your turns, you can deal 1d4 bludgeoning
> damage to one creature grappled by you.
>
> **Horseback Flyby Charger** Your mount can take a Dash or Disengage as a bonus action, provided you made an attack against a creature after moving at least 20ft, and hit.
>
> #### Weapon Mastery
>
> Your dedication in honing your battle skills with specific weapons
> gives you an edge against enemies, as well as many tricks hidden up
> your sleeve. Starting from 2nd level, choose two types of weapons, or
> one type of weapon and a shield, to be your mastered weapons. While you
> wield only your mastered weapons you gain the following benefits.
>
> **Parry** When hostile creature hits you with a melee attack, you can use your reaction to add your proficiency bonus to your AC for that
> attack, potentially causing the attack to miss you.
>
> **Harmful strike** As a bonus action, you can choose to deal an additional 1d6 damage to your next weapon attack. This damage die changes to 1d8 at 7th level, and to 1d12 at 14th level.
> You can use either of these options a number of times equal to your
> proficiency modifier, and you regain all expended uses after you
> finish a long rest.
>
> When you gain new level in this class you can change your choice of
> mastered weapons, representing you shifting your training, as you
> focus on a usage of different weapon types.
>
> #### As Good as My Word
>
> Cultural implications of your view as a Sir Knight is widely known.  Starting from 2nd level, you have advantage on Persuasion and Intimidation skill checks when dealing with creatures coming from races or cultures which knighthood left a significant imprint upon, such as humans, bugbears, hobgoblins, and many more.

> #### Way of Life
>
> At 3rd level choose your Way of Life Archetype. Choose between the Inquisitor or Commander, both detailed at the end of the class description. Your choice grants you features at 3rd level, and again at 6th, 9th, 13th and 20th level.
>
> #### Ability Score Improvement
>
> When you reach 4th level, and again at 8th, 10th, 12th, 16th and 19th
> level, you can increase one ability score of your choice by 2, or you
> can increase two ability scores of your choice by 1. As normal, you
> can't increase an ability score above 20 using this feature.
>
> #### Extra attack
>
> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.
>
> The number of attacks increases to three when you reach 11th level in
> this class.
>
> #### Weapon Mastery improvement
>
> As you gain more and more experience in battle your deadly arsenal
> widens. Starting from 7th level, while you wield only your mastered
> weapons you gain the following benefits.
>
> **Clinch control** If you successfully parry an attack you can choose to grapple your enemy. As a bonus action on your turn you can attempt to shove a creature grappled by you in this way. Alternatively, you can use your bonus action to lock your weapon with weapon of creature you are grappling, making it impossible to use both weapons until the grapple ends.
>
> **Peripheral vision** As a reaction, you can give yourself advantage on Dexterity saving throws against effects that you can see, such as
> traps and spells. To gain this benefit, you can't be blinded,
> deafened, or incapacitated. You can also choose to use your reaction to
> ignore half cover and three-quarters cover on your attack, potentially
> causing this attack to hit.
>
> You can use either of these options a number of times equal to your proficiency modifier, and you regain all expended uses after you finish a long rest.
>
> #### Weight control
>
> Starting from 14th level you can wield versatile weapons with one arm
> and benefit from it like wielding it with two hands, and when you use
> a weapon with heavy property, this weapon lacks this property for you.
> Also your carrying capacity doubles.
>
> #### Weapon Mastery improvement
>
> You are becoming a grandmaster in battle arts. Starting from 14th level, while you wield only your mastered weapons you gain the following benefits.
>
> **Masterful Athlete** As an action you can choose to sprint, which gives you extra movement for the current turn. The increase equals triple your speed, after applying any modifiers. You cannot choose to sprint if you used this action on your previous turn.
>
> **Positioning** As a reaction, you can give yourself a benefit of a half-cover until the end of the current turn.
>
> You can use either of these options a number of times equal to your
> proficiency modifier, and you regain all expended uses after you
> finish a long rest.
>
> #### Paragon of Verity
>
> Starting at 15th level, if you are telling the truth, any creature
> that can understand you knows you are telling the truth. Additionally
> you can not be forced to state a lie if you do not wish to, and any
> magic or feature used against you fails and stops working the instant
> it would attempt to make you lie.
>
> #### Adamantine Soul
>
> Your resolve is a tale of legends. Beginning at 17th level your alignment cannot be forcibly changed, and you become proficient in Charisma saving throws.
>
> #### Perfect Warrior
>
> There is little more a master like you can achieve on a battlefield.
> Starting at 18th level, you can use your weapon mastery options
> regardless of weapons or shields you wield. Additionally, you honed
> your precision to unthinkable extent, allowing you to forcibly push
> yourself beyond mortal level. When you roll for an attack roll,
> ability check, saving throw or damage roll, you can forgo rolling and
> take maximal possible result from dice instead.  When you use this
> feature, you gain one level of exhaustion.

#### And the subclasses:

#### Inquisitor

> You choose to give your life in the name of protecting decent folk
> from the machinations of magic, from horrors beyond the mortal sight,
> from the unknown of darkness. You study magic, for you need to know
> your enemy. You have eye for details, for you need to wage war where
> enemy lurks exactly behind your back. But in the end your fire will
> disperse the darkness.
>
> #### Know your enemy
>
> When you choose this way of life at 3rd level, you gain proficiency in
> the Arcana and Insight skills if you don't already have it.
>
> #### Tools for the Job
>
> When you reach 3rd level, you gain the ability to cast a limited
> number of spells. You can cast the following spells, requiring no
> material components: detect evil and good, detect magic, detect poison
> and disease, identify, sanctuary, protection from evil and good, find
> traps and purify food and drink.  Charisma is your spellcasting ability
> for spells gained from this subclass, and your spell save DC = 8 +
> your proficiency bonus + your Charisma modifier. You can cast each of
> these spells once, and you regain ability to do so after you finish a
> long rest.
>
> You also learn Create Bonfire and Control Flames cantrips.
>
> #### And the Pyres will Burn
>
> Starting at 6th level, when you cast Create Bonfire, the spell creates
> a magic bonfire that fills a 10-foot cube instead. Additionally, you
> can use your bonus action on your turn to move the bonfire to another
> location within range.
>
> #### Nowhere to Run
>
> Even if someone is adept at running away, you are master of chase.
> Starting at 9th level, when you see a creature cast a spell or use a
> feature to teleport somewhere, you can use your reaction to foil the
> escape. Your target must make a Intelligence saving throw with DC
> equal to your spell save DC.  On a failure, the teleportation attempt
> is a failure, and the spell slot, if used, is wasted.
>
> You can use this feature a number of times equal to your Charisma
> modifier (minimum of 1), and regain all expended uses after a long
> rest.
>
> #### Defend the Innocent
>
> Starting at 13th level, you gain resistance to damage from spells.
> Additionally, you can use your reaction to give this resistance to
> another willing creature that you can see, no further than 30ft from you,
> until the start of your next turn.
>
> You can use this feature a number of times equal to your Charisma
> modifier (minimum of 1), and regain all expended uses after a long
> rest.
>
> #### They Can See Only Fire
>
> Your soul is a burning hell for all that sin, and eyes are the windows
> of the soul. Starting at 20th level, each creature of your choice
> within 30 feet of you that can see you must make a Wisdom saving throw
> against your spell save DC. If the creature's alignment is evil it
> makes the saving throw with disadvantage. If the creature fails, it
> looks into your eyes and sees every single sin it has ever committed.
> The creature is then frightened of you. While frightened in this way
> creature cannot target you or include you in area of effect of any
> spell or ability. Affected creatures can repeat the saving throw at
> the start of their turns, provided you are not within the line of
> sight. If a creature's saving throw is successful or the effect ends
> for it, the creature is immune to this feature for the next 24 hours.

#### Commander

> You chose your life is to lead others, seek glory in great battles,
> raise armies and command them, lead them to victory. You are a shining
> example for others, you inspire men and woman to follow your lead and
> rise in the path of greatness.
>
> #### Mount and Blade
>
> Starting at 3rd level, your mastery as a rider becomes apparent. You
> have advantage on saving throws made to avoid falling off your mount.
> If you fall off your mount and descend no more than 10 feet, you can
> land on your feet if you're not incapacitated.
>
> Finally, mounting or dismounting a creature costs you only 5 feet of
> movement, rather than half your speed.
>
> #### Call to arms
>
> You raise your voice, rallying your most trusted companions to battle.
> Starting at 3rd level, you can choose a number of friendly creatures
> equal to your Charisma ability modifier (minimum of one), which become
> rallied for one minute. Those creatures gain temporary hit points
> equal to your level in this class + your Charisma ability modifier.
> While rallied, once every turn each creature can add your Charisma
> modifier to one of its weapon damage rolls, provided it still has
> temporary hit points. If a creature loses all those temporary hit
> points, it instead can add your Charisma modifier to its saving throw
> for the remaining duration.
>
> After you use this feature you cannot do so again until you finish a
> long rest.
>
> #### Share ability
>
> Starting at 6th level, you can use your reaction and expend one use of
> chosen weapon mastery feature to grant chosen benefit to one friendly
> creature that you can see.
>
> #### Divide and Conquer
>
> Starting at 9th level, when you reduce a creature to 0 hit points you
> can make another attack as a part of the same attack action against
> another enemy within your range. After that, you cannot use this
> feature again until the start of your next turn.
>
> #### The last Obstacle
>
> Starting at 13th level, as an action you can designate a creature. If
> the target is reduced to 0 hit points, you and each creature friendly
> to you in 60 foot radius regains hit points equal to your level in
> this class + your Charisma modifier.
>
> After you use this feature you cannot do so again until you finish a
> long rest.
>
> #### Banner Lord
>
> When you reach 20th level, your mere presence bolster the morale of
> your allies. If you are not unconscious, you and each friendly
> creature in a 120ft radius that can see you gains temporary hit points
> equal to 5 + your Charisma modifier at the start of each of its turns.

Oh, and multiclass options, if they provide anything:

> **Prerequisites**. To qualify for multiclassing into the Sir Knight class,
> you must meet these prerequisites: 15 Strength or 15 Dexterity
>
> **Proficiencies**. When you multiclass into the Sir Knight class, you gain
> the following proficiencies: simple weapons, martial weapons, light
> armor, medium armor, vehicles(land)

Comment: @SeriousBri I think without an explanation of *what* you find awkward about the class name, it isn't very constructive. I'm not sure whether that feedback is better suited to answer or comment though. Cezaryx, regarding the name, it would be useful to know the specific inspirations behind it (to your best ability to articulate it). Also, just to confirm, this is your work, right? It's maybe the dndwiki link which throws me off.

Comment: @Someone_Evil Yes, this is my class, I wrote it and posted on dndwiki, but considering no one coud/wanted/cared to give feedback or anything really, I figured posting here and trying my luck is a start. Considering the name, well, I am not a native speaker, and I really thought this is okay name. What was on my mind? From one side a name of the social layer: knight, and on the other a title of Sir given, like, dunno Sir Eik or Sir Galahad. And combining them into one, and in my native language that combination is normal to say. But if in english this sounds poorly or wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Ah, the main issue I see is that it reads like a name or address. (it's a bit like having options like "Dr. Wizard") It's also redundant: Generally (/formally), "Sir" is the title/honorific given to Knights. You could probably just drop the "Sir" altogether.

Comment: I'd recommend "Noble Knight" as the name of your class, considering the point you make and that @Someone_Evil makes.  Your efforts for this home brew are commendable, I'll try to offer you an answer later today.

Comment: I made an edit to your question for formatting and grammar/spelling. Please to not edit in recommendations for answers into this question. Give it a few days, and if you want another scrub after you get a few answers, then post a second version as a second question . (This is per our Meta on Homebrew Review guidelines).

Comment: This reads like "Fighter, but better", is that your intention?

Comment: @Caleth I believe fighter as a main class still does more damage(both burst and as consistent damage) than this one, but knight have bigger versatility as a base. Considering versatility is more important that damage, then yes, it is better.

Comment: OK, glad it was helpful, the bonfire point is certainly a mechanical difference.  I'll re read the weight control again and see what I missed. (And again I commend you for the level of effort you put into this homebrew).  

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you play tested the weight control feature?  It looks as though it makes a warhammer or long sword to 1d10 one handed, and a quarterstaff do 1d8, but I am not sure what you are seeing as the benefit here. Is this so that halfling's or gnomes can use longbows or greatswords without disadvantage?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast You will laugh at me, but a friend suggested that I do something to increase average damage of the class past 11th, so I did that to grant it whopping increase by average 3 points of damage when wielding a shield. It also works better with 18th level feature, and crits. Although if you decide to not use shield at all, you propably do not get benefits from this.

Comment: @Someone_Evil 'Sir Knight' _is_ redundant.  Another reason to change it is that traditionally it is gendered, with female knights being addressed as 'Dame' rather than 'Sir'.  If the class is open to women (as the Commander Way of Life suggests), an ungendered title would be better.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Agreed that 'Noble Knight' sounds better, although still a bit redundant (since Knight is typically the lowest form of nobility) and a bit culturally dependent (since the class might be available in cultures without a feudal/noble system, and at least the Inquisitor Way of Life sounds like it might be tied to a church hierarchy independent of nobility).  'Heroic Knight' or 'Warrior Paragon' are my first thoughts, but I have to admit neither _sound_ as good as 'Noble Knight'.

Comment: @Kirt maybe even Courtly Knight but that may too restrictive, and Honorable Knight might capture the whole status and Truth Telling thing.  Wordsmithing can be a mess sometimes. Other options include:  noble-born, titled, patrician, high-born, well born, gentle, righteous, virtuous, good, honorable, worthy, lofty

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Recommended balance changes to Noble Knight

Yes, a name change is one of the suggestions for thematic reasons.

1. Change the name to Noble Knight.
   Why?  Based [on our comments discussion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/195343/is-this-homebrew-sir-knight-class-balanced#comment527933_195343) (and you searching for a term that fits in not-your-native-tongue) **Noble Knight** almost exactly captures the overall theme of your medieval knight concept, while "Sir Knight" is more a form of address.
2. Change the *As Good as My Word* Cultural Implications entry to read:

> Cultural implications of your view as a Noble Knight are widely known.  Starting at 2nd level, you have advantage on Persuasion and Intimidation skill checks when dealing with creatures of humanoid who come from races or cultures where knighthood left a significant imprint.

Why?  This is going to vary by campaign, so giving example races is a case of both too much specificity and not enough.  That's a tidier way to say what you are trying to say.

3. Your 7th level feature is overfilled with features.
   a. Peripheral Vision is overly loaded with features.  Suggest you remove the "you can also" feature, a*nd make it an always on feature*.  The ignoring of half and three quarter cover doesn't seem to fit the feature.
4. Multiclassing  - change the prerequisites to this:

> **Prerequisites**. To qualify for multiclassing into the Sir Knight class, you must meet these prerequisites: 13 Strength or 13 Dexterity

Why? Be consistent with how MC works in this edition.

5. Tools for the Job
   a. First off, *keep the cantrips*.  Nice thematic touch.
   b. Suggest that either these can be cast as a ritual once per long rest, or, you cast any of them a number of times equal to proficiency bonus per long rest and not as a ritual.

Why?  That's a pile of spells to get all at once, and, as a point of comparison, the Barbarian gets a similar ability (to cast two utility spells as a ritual) as a Totem Warrior at third level.  Since you link a lot of stuff to proficiency bonus, I suggest that you increase how many spells you can cast per long rest by indexing to proficiency bonus.  (At level 5, for example, 3 rather than 2).  This will reflect the "get better as you go up in level" concept that you generally have.

6. As to **And the Pyres will Burn**

> Starting at 6th level, when you cast Create Bonfire, the spell creates
> a magic bonfire that fills a 10-foot cube instead. Additionally, you
> can use your bonus action on your turn to move the bonfire to another
> location within range.

Your teleporting bonfire, up to 60 feet per round, is more mobile than Flaming Sphere.  You need to restrict the distance that you can move it per round to 30' or even less.
Here is "why" the "even less" is my recommendation.  This feature as written is better than 2d level spell *flaming sphere*.  Since you are using a class feature, it being a little more powerful is OK, but, because it does more damage than flaming sphere I'll recommend that it's movement be limited to 10 or 15'.   From a cinematic PoV, the bonfire slides rather than teleports, or rolls over, so having a 10' bonfire roll 10' 'looks' more like a moving flame.  Yes, this suggestion is an appeal to both balance and verisimilitude.  Other spells that have a moving AoE, like Moonbeam, also inform this suggestion.

7. Call to Arms.  This is too fiddly.  Remove the following and it fits better.

> If a creature loses all those temporary hit points, it instead can add
> your Charisma modifier to its saving throw for the remaining duration.

8. The Last Obstacle
   Change the *HP gives healing* to *adding Temp HP* to be consistent.
9. Weight Control: I had originally assessed this as a possible means to Dual Wield great axes and two handed swords but your comment allayed that concern.  The bonus to versatile weapons (war hammer/longsword) is nice but not over the top.

#### Overall evaluation

As with a lot of home brew, the temptation to add too many features is hard to resist.  It was a good idea to get a scrub from other perspectives.   My only *significant* concern is the Weight Control feature since it overwrites a core game mechanical aspect of melee combat.

These are some up front changes I'd make to keep the balance point closer to somewhere between Paladin and Fighter.  Overall, I would need to play test the Inquisitor option a bit to see what might break, but the Commander seems to fit within the balance box if you make the corrections I suggested above.

Comment: "later today"...we've been had.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov As I edited the Q for format and grammar (OP is not a native speaker, I figured the assist would help) most of an answer formed inside my brain.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Thank you for your help with editing and feedback. 1,2,4,5,7, 8 suggestions are clear for me and make a lot of sense, although about rest. 3: but Weight Control does not apply for two-handed weapons, it "only" increases die for versatile when wielded in one hand, which you can dual wield already.  6:  There is a significant difference between moonbeam, flaming sphere and create bonfire: they deal effect either in your turn, or at the start of enemy's, bonfire only if you end your turn in its area, so I've seen this more as a control ability, and for that big range was needed.

Comment: I agree that 'Noble Knight' sounds better, but in addition to my comments on the OP, 'Noble' is unfortunately also the name of an official _background_.  So while we might have (for example) a 'Ranger (Folk Hero)' or a 'Wizard (Criminal)', here we could have a 'Noble Knight (Noble)'.  Not a dealbreaker, but unfortunate - any other names possible?

Comment: @Kirt Courtly Knight might fit (status and social) or Vigil Knight (which is a reach) and I don't see there being a problem with the background ... let me do a litle more word smithing, I might find a better fit. Gallant Knight or Knight Errant might fit well enough, or Gentleman Knight

Comment: I like Honorable Knight

Comment: @Kirt it gets worse, a variant of the Noble background is Knight, so we could reasonably expect a "Noble Knight (Noble (Knight))"

Comment: @Caleth That would be awesome, though.  NK^2

Answer (score 11):

### Horseback Flyby Charger is broken

I agree with @KorvinStarmast answers, but wanted to add that Horseback Flyby Charger looks broken.

It would allow a player to kite 60ft in and out while disengaging on a single turn, making it impossible for many melee combatants to hit you, or to kite 90ft in and out, making it easy to run in, attack a ranged combatant, and then run out of effective range, or out of line of sight, making it very difficult for a ranged character to ever hit you.

I do like the idea though, and it could be balanced down.

**Some ideas for a fix:**
The following are in rough order of power. All would need to be play tested, its hard to ensure a clever player couldn't abuse them.

When you attack (or when you hit) a creature who was more than 10ft away on the start of your turn, ...

- it has disadvantage on opportunity attacks against you
- you have +2 AC on it's opportunity attacks against you
- it makes a Dexterity save of 10 + your proficiency. If it fails, it cannot make opportunity attacks against you. (My favorite, but it may slow down the game a bit)
- our mount can take a Dash or Disengage as a bonus action. You cannot use this ability again until you take a long or short rest.

Comment: I am glad you said that, I thought it is too much for a fighting style. That being said, there is no fighting style for mounted combat at all and I wanted to give this class one, so what would you propose, of course if you have a proposition that is overall good to go?

Comment: @Cezaryx I added some ideas for fixes, many of which have knobs you could turn if they seem too strong or weak.

Answer (score 5):

#### Just play a Fighter or Paladin with a Noble Background.

In general, classes should cover broad archetypes, with more fine-grained distinctions being the domain of subclasses and Backgrounds. In the case of this "class", it is clearly just a Fighter or Paladin with the Noble Background, from a conceptual perspective - so, that's exactly what they should be. As a result, I'm going to answer you with a frame challenge: this "class" shouldn't exist to begin with, since it misunderstands what classes even are. At most, you could maybe justify it being a Fighter or Paladin subclass.

Comment: Well, official classes do need to be broad to accomodate for as much as they can for player's sake. Not everything can be archieved by them, nor there are official abilities or spells that allow for certain mechanics. I do not need to make something as broad as possible, bc I do not make an official class, but homebrew one, as per DMG page 288. Your answer sadly does not provide any value for me, do not answer any of the posted questions, neither it is a frame challenge bc "not" creating a class is not an answer for a class' balancing and implementing ideas, neither it is helpful in any way.

Comment: But the idea is not to create a player character for certain vibe, but a class option. It's not even me who will play it.

Comment: @nick012000 FWIW, the AD&D 1e UA class Cavalier did something similar in terms of social class and status in departing from the stock "Fighter" chassis.  While I see your point in terms of a frame challenge (does this niche not already exist) the unfortunate attempts at something like this as a sub class (Purple Dragon Knight for example) didn't quite fit the niche as well as one would hope.  Like any home brew, this probably needs some play testing.  (I am in a game where we are play testing a homebrew dragon rider that the DM and I both did a first pass edit on: play test helps a lot.

Comment: Oh dear.  IMO, the 1e UA Cavalier (along with most of the rest of that book) was feature bloat incarnate.  I like how the idea of highly specialized class roles was converted in 2e into kits.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer Likewise. I found that the kits approach was cleaner.